# Implement a single class for View Transitions in iOS App?

Tags: iphone, ios, design-patterns, architecture

I want to follow MVC for my current project, in which 7-8 `UIViewController` subclasses will be there.
There are more than 30 classes (`NSObject`subclasses) for maintaining data and server connections.
Most of the time server connection manager class will send local notifications to `UIViewController` subclassess to make view transitions. I want to make it happen in centralized manner. Meaning from a single class.

What I want to do is, Implement a single class which handles all my `UIViewController` Transitions.

Any idea on how I can implement this ???

Note: I don't know the pros and cons of following this kind of approach. Even I don't know this is feasible or not.

Comment: what do you mean by transitions?

Comment: Transitions as it means: moving from one view to another. and moving back again and so on and on.

Comment: I know what the word means, but what i wanted to know does he mean like push pop and present? or some more custom ones like the one i added in my answer bellow

Comment: Nothing related to animations.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, you would for example have a function in a global place like (pushController: , popController: etc...)?

Comment: You mean to implement transition logic or animations???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you mean. My best bet, would be a singleton, that would receive two `UIViewController`s references and then would apply the animations between the two. This way you would have a centralized place where you could your animations. Probably a more complete solution, would be receiving the two `UIViewControllers` and two blocks, one for the animation block and another one for the completion block.